# Merging datasets with different dimensions

Tags: r, merge

Given `df1` as

```
df1 = data.frame(a = c(1,2,2), 
b = c(2, 2, 3), c = c(3, 2, 1), 
label = c("abc", "bbb", "bca"))

> df1
  a b c label
1 1 2 3   abc
2 2 2 2   bbb
3 2 3 1   bca
```

and `df2` as

```
df2 = data.frame(a = c(2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2), b = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3), 
c = c(2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1), d = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.9))

> df2
  a b c   d
1 2 2 2 0.1
2 2 2 2 0.2
3 1 2 3 0.8
4 1 2 3 0.7
5 1 2 3 0.6
6 2 3 1 0.9
```

What is the best way to merge them in order to get `df3` as following?

```
df3 = data.frame(a = c(2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2), b = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3), 
c = c(2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1), d = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.9), 
label = c("bbb", "bbb", "abc", "abc", "abc", "bca"))

> df3
  a b c   d label
1 2 2 2 0.1   bbb
2 2 2 2 0.2   bbb
3 1 2 3 0.8   abc
4 1 2 3 0.7   abc
5 1 2 3 0.6   abc
6 2 3 1 0.9   bca
```

I want the output to be the same size as `df2` with all its attributes and values, plus an additional `label` column from `df1` which indicates the unique combination group of `a`, `b`, `c` attributes.

I tried the basic `merge` function as

```
df4 = merge(df1, df2)
```

and it works fine for my sample data frames (like this example here), but when I want to apply this logic to larger data sets it doesn't return the output I expect. Specially the size of out put is *not* the same size as `df2`, but smaller size.

I was wondering if there is any alternative way to do this, or any idea about what can goes wrong applying the same logic (which seems to work fine in small data frames) in large data sets. Thanks!

Comment: It's probably a smaller size because there are some (a, b, c) combinations that appear in `df2` but not `df1`. If you want to keep all the rows from `df2`, just add `all.y=TRUE` as an argument to `merge`.

Comment: Please see the marked duplicate -- you are looking for a right outer join.